# How do I iterate through cells in a specific column using openpyxl 1.6

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am currently using Python 2.7 and so far have been able to make it this far. I need to print the value of cells in column D till the maximum row the excel sheet has.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Something')
for row in range(2, sheet.get_highest_row()):
   bla=str(row)
   status  = sheet['D' + bla].value()
   print status
```

Which gives a traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "ExcelAnalysis.py", line 25, in <module>
    status  = sheet['D' + bla].value()
 TypeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: **SOLVED**  for cow in range(1, sheet.get_highest_row()):  
       status  = sheet.cell(row=cow, column=3).value

Comment: Pardon my formatting, It's my first question here

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using an outdated version of `openpyxl`, update it:

```
pip install --upgrade openpyxl
```

And, you should not be calling `value`, it is a property:

```
status = sheet['D' + bla].value
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't have that option @alecxe

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very primitive and not very optimized way, but I got the answer nevertheless.

```
for cow in range(1, sheet.get_highest_row()):
   status  = sheet.cell(row=cow, column=3).value
```

Please, If anyone can, help me improve it.
Thank you very much in advance.

See more on [this page](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/315/openpyxl-xlsx-file-cell-value-none)